# Does an open source alternative to ESRI's Image Server exist?

Tags: open-source-gis, imagery

I noticed the default way to store imagery is by using a database in the open source world.
I like ESRI's Image Server software because it removes the need for a database and makes backing up a lot easier since its just files.

Is there an Image Server type software in the open source world?

Comment: changed the title slightly..

Comment: not sure I agree with your premise, most of the open source raster software I'm familiar with stores data in files directly. Are their specific features of Image Server you're interested in?

Comment: I agree with SCW.  There are some less mature OpenSource projects making the case for storing rasters in db's, but this is something that has really been more prevalent in ESRI's world ala rasters in SDE.       I am most familiar with MapServer, where the common approach has been to store tiled rasters on disk and access them through a vector tile-index.

Comment: I guess the convenience of Image Server is that it has many free clients that connect to it. Like they have an AutoCad client that lets you bring in aerials from Image Server. Does a client like that exist for MapServer?

Comment: MapServer can serve WMS and WCS.  Any client that can consume these services could use the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are open source alternatives.

http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/

http://zoomhub.net/

Comment: This is very nice!

Comment: I like these. It really depends what u want out of Image Server.  If its just for serving up 'imagery' as a basemap, then use cached services (Esri or non-esri).  If you want to do fancy stuff like change the bands of the underlying imagery, change the histogram stretch, etc, then the above answers don't help
http://serverapps.esri.com/javascript_examples/image_service_band_spinners.html

Id like to see an Open Source equivalent that matches Image Server's capabilities.
http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/serverimage/key-features.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with esri image server, but mapserver and geoserver support wms, by using just files and no database, and which can be served to eg arcgis. If your client supports it you could use tilecache as well (wms-c) which will cache the result and make your applications a lot faster.